# SpeechRecognitionEngine in the Xamarin android app

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, speech-recognition

Is contains something the same in Xamarin android framework?

I want my app can listning recognition in any moment but when I try use SpeechRecognitionEngine/SpeechSyntax in Xamarin I get error "Speech is not supported in this platform". But when I use TextToSpeech it works.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/speech

Comment: @Jason Is it alone solution? This solution call google recognition. I want my app listen speaker on background without extra activity and windows.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Speech Service is a cloud-based API that offers the following functionality:

Speech-to-text transcribes audio files or streams to text.

Text-to-speech converts input text into human-like synthesized speech.

Speech translation enables real-time, multi-language translation for both speech-to-text and speech-to-speech.

Voice assistants can create human-like conversation interfaces for applications.

You can check this document to get more information:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/azure-cognitive-services/speech-recognition